# mapDispatchToProps not working on button click - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch event to my reducer using arguments as follows, but even after clicking button dispatch is not fired:

Import statement for Action:

`import { saveDetails } from "../actions";`

Button which dispatches the action

```
<Button title="Save Information" onPress={props.callPostApi({
          name: "Chetan S",
          age: "26",
          salary: "30000"
        })}
      />

//here { name: "Chetan S", age: "26", salary: "30000" } is an object to be passed as parameter
```

Function to Map Dispatch to Props :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    callPostApi: dataToSave => {
      dispatch(saveDetails(dataToSave));
    }
  };
};
```

Exporting the component as:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostComponent);
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `onPress={()=>yourFunction()}`

Comment: @prasanth adding ```onPress={() => props.callPostApi({...})}``` worked ! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help :) @Chetan S

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap your callback with in function like this using ES6 Arrow function

`onPress={()=>yourFunction()}`

> Because if You are using like this below
>
> `onPress={yourFunction()}`
>
> They will run the function on document load.That means component while
>   mount.That why its not working on press.
>
> So if you wrap with in function. its will execute only press the button

Comment: That's pretty useful, Thanks ! :)